# What is TypeError: unbound method form_feedback? on Odoo or Python

Tags: python, odoo

I have a odoo payment gateway module.This is actually v10/new api module.Everything is working fine as expected except payment return.Once done the payment and return to site it shows 500 internal server error.Here is what log says

File "/opt/odoo/addons/payment_lkpay/controllers/main.py", line 34, in lkpay_validate_data
    '/payment/lkpay/accept/'],
TypeError: unbound method form_feedback() must be called with payment.transaction instance as first argument (got Cursor instance instead)

This is what I have written in controllers> main.py

```
def lkpay_validate_data(self, **post):

lkpay = request.env['payment.acquirer'].search([('provider', '=', 'lkpay')], limit=1)
            _logger.debug('lkpay: validated data')

return request.env['payment.transaction'].sudo().form_feedback(post, 'lkpay')
        _logger.warning('lkpay data are corrupted')

return False
```

Can anyone point me the issue?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with everything here, but it seems the 'sudo' function is returning a Cursor, which is not what you meant.

Comment: Can you attach the code of function "form_feedback()"?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:-

def lkpay_validate_data(self, **post):

lkpay = request.env['payment.acquirer'].sudo().search([('provider', '=', 'lkpay')], limit=1)
            _logger.debug('lkpay: validated data')

return request.env['payment.transaction'].sudo().form_feedback(post, 'lkpay')
        _logger.warning('lkpay data are corrupted')

return False